# Add post on facebook with url,text and image objective c

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I want to post image,text and applink with the project.
I am using below code for this.But it is not working.
It only allow url and image to share. but not text

```
    NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
      NSString *text = @"How to add Facebook and Twitter sharing to an iOS app";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/02/how-to-add-facebook-and-twitter-sharing-to-an-ios-app/"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"roadfire-icon-square-200"];

UIActivityViewController *controller =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
 initWithActivityItems:@[text, url, image]
 applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that FB no longer allows developer to pre-fill post message. You should refer this document

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#ios-integration

> Use of the iOS share sheet is subject to Facebook Platform Policy,
>   including section 2.3 which states that apps may not pre-fill in the
>   context of the share sheet.